# Is there a way to use a value recently gotten to look for other? in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to make a query and use a value gotten to look for other in the same query.
My collection is like this:

```
{
"houses": {
    123: {
      "color": "white",
      "location": "California"
    },
    124: {
      "color": "blue",
      "location": "Las Vegas"
   }
},
"owners": {
   "Anne": {
     "house": 124,
   },
   "Jake": {
     "house": 123
   }
 }
}
```

Before doing the query I will know just the name of the owner and I would like to get the house information (color, location).

What I'm asking is that if there's a way of using the house number to get the house info in the same query. Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {'$project' {'houses': 1, 'house_number': '$owners.Anne.house'}}, 
  {'$project': {'house_info': 'houses.$house_number':1}}
])
```

I tried making the house number a string and concat it with $houses but mongo doesn't let me concat the $ symbol.
I am avoiding to make two queries, one for getting the house number and then a second one for getting the house information.

Could someone please help me with this? Sorry if I can't explain myself very well, english isn't my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite possible with the use of [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operators. The $objectToArray is to convert the houses object / document to an array of key/value
properties. With this array you can filter using the '$owners.Anne.house' value.

Take for instance this aggregate pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        { '$project': {
            'house_info': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$houses' },
                'cond': {
                    '$eq': ['$owners.Anne.house', '$$this.k']
                    }
                }
            }
        } }
])
```

The result is something like :

```
{
    'house_info': [
        {
            k: '124',
            v: {
                "color": "blue",
                "location": "Las Vegas"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get just the data document

```
{
    "color": "blue",
    "location": "Las Vegas"
}
```

Add a further projection pipeline stage that uses [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator as

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$project': {
        'house_array': {
        '$filter': {
            'input': { '$objectToArray': '$houses' },
            'cond': {
                '$eq': ['$owners.Anne.house', '$$this.k']
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$project': {
        'house_info': {
            '$arrayElemAt':  ['$house_array', 0]
        }
    } }
])
```